# Phalanger error in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, phalanger

I have installed Phalanger from http://phalanger.codeplex.com/ and installed Phalanger Tools from the built-in market-place function in my Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate distribution. After doing this, every time I boot start Visual Studio I get a dialog-box with the error:

If I examine ActivityLog.xml I find the following errors (all other elements omitted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="ActivityLog.xsl"?>
<activity>

  <entry>
    <record>16</record>
    <time>2013/10/04 14:43:55.426</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Loading UI library</description>
    <guid>{712C84E3-B447-4283-ABF3-D00B161E63FE}</guid>
    <hr>800a006f</hr>
    <errorinfo>Cannot find the requested resource.</errorinfo>
  </entry>


  <entry>
    <record>63</record>
    <time>2013/10/04 14:44:03.569</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>SetSite failed for package [PHP.Project.PHPProjectPackage, PHP.VS, Version=1.8.4608.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17116b35d45f8bb8]</description>
    <guid>{9DD0D70B-6760-4C96-B1DC-03AAF937D95A}</guid>
    <hr>80004003 - E_POINTER</hr>
    <errorinfo>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>64</record>
    <time>2013/10/04 14:44:03.574</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [PHP.Project.PHPProjectPackage, PHP.VS, Version=1.8.4608.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17116b35d45f8bb8]</description>
    <guid>{9DD0D70B-6760-4C96-B1DC-03AAF937D95A}</guid>
    <hr>80004003 - E_POINTER</hr>
    <errorinfo>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
</activity>
```

Does anyone have a take on what I could do to relieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seams, you have PHP Tools for Visual Studio, not Phalanger Tools. Also it is possible you installed PHP Tools in addition to Phalanger Tools.

Try to uninstall both, and install Phalanger Tools only.

Comment: Alright, I see they might be conflicting sadly it did not resolve the problem. I uninstalled PHP Tools for Visual Studio, I cannot find a reference to anything only called PHP tools. Please advice.

Comment: Ok, so I've got PHP working in my project now, even though my Visual Studio distribution is still behaving like an angry bull throwing errors around.